# Invalid call hook error but the hook seems valid

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to use `useContext` hook and I get an error - `Invalid hook call`.
I read the docs in React's website, but it seems like nothing is wrong here.
Tried to reinstall the application and got the same error, so I guess it is not a cached error or anything of that nature.
This is what I have:

```
const customCard = (item: Item) => {

  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return(
     <View>
       .....
     </View>
  )
}
```

According to the error, the problem is in `const { theme }` line.
I have this exact line in other files and it is working just fine, so I can't understand why in this file it happens.

I read somewhere that this may be a duplication of `node_moduels` causing this error, so I deleted `node_modules` and `npm install` again but it still didn't work.

This component is used to render an item from a list with a flatlist.

```
<FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{padding: 8}}
        data={items}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => customCard(items[index])}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
```

Comment: Try write `const customCard = (item: Item) => {`   like `const CustomCard = ({item: Item}) => {`

Comment: @KonstantinModin Thanks, I tried but it is not working.

Comment: @JohnDoah can you share where and how are you using this component?

Comment: @KartikMalik Sure! I added it to the original post.

Comment: @JohnDoah got it

Answer (score 0):

you must be defining `customCard` inside the component where you have used the FlatList component

you should Define CustomCard as a separate component otherwise it will consider it to be a function as you can't define a component inside a component.

```
const CustomCard = (item: Item) => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return(
     <View>
       .....
     </View>
  )
}



const App () => {
  const items = [];
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
        <FlatList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{padding: 8}}
            data={items}
            renderItem={({item}) => <CustomCard item={item}/>}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

let me know if there is anything else I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I have ```customCard``` in a separate file and not the same file as the FlatList. Does it count as separate or because I'm using it in FlatList and it's in another file it's considered as a function? I'm new to React in general so I'm a little confused.

Comment: It will be a component only

Comment: So that should be ok? or should I still put this in the same file?

Comment: Both will be okay if it is a big component then it's better to keep it in a separate file. I usually keep it in a different file.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there anything else I can do to solve this problem? I tried searching the internet but found nothing. When I had this problem in another file, only a rewrite helped me to solve this. but this file is a little bigger and I try to avoid rewriting it.

Comment: Ah I see you must be using some things from its parent, in that case shifting it to another file would be a real pain. you can still do one thing just shift the component and pass everything as a prop, this is the only solution to this. or you have to rewrite everything.

Comment: One more point I just come across, if you are using a hook inside your component(flatlist item) then that component is not stateless which might cause some issue. As FlatList unmounts a component when it is away from the view so your state might be lost. Just a side note it was.